# CSS how to show menu sub li when menu has position fixed

Tags: html, css

I suppose the title is confusing so I will explain the issue:
I have menu that has position fixed and this must stay this way. The problem is with all sub li items that are at the bottom of the menu - they are not visible all. I have prepared jsfiddle for you :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkxwqn7L/1/)

if you hover on Travel li you will be able to see only 2 sub li and if they are more they stay hidden.. 
The question is Is it possible to change sub li order position so if the are in the bottom the sub li listing to go up and if it is a top sub li the listing to go to bottom?
Please visit the jsfiddle to better understand the issue..

the html is:

```
<div id="menu" style="display: block;">
    <h2>Browse our categories</h2>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="catmenu">
            <li class="main"><a href="accountants">Accountants</a>
                <ul class="subul">
                    <li><a href="travel-2">Accountants1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="travel-agents">Accountants2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="travel-agents">Accountants3</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li class="main"><a href="automotive">Automotive</a></li>
            <li class="main"><a href="building">Building</a></li>
            <li class="main"><a href="business-services">Business services</a></li>
            <li class="main with"><a href="travel">Travel</a>
                <ul class="subul"><li><a href="travel-2">Travel 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="travel-agents">Travel agents2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="travel-agents">Travel agents3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Everything seems fine on Chrome.

Comment: I tested on IE10 and Mozilla, on both I can see only 2sub li for Travel - do you see all 3 sub li?

Comment: and this is the reason I am looking for solution to make bottom sub li to go up, not down..

Comment: Obviously this depends on your browser size. Yes, someone on a bigger browser will see all 3 items. Someone on a smaller browser will see none. You can't solve this issue with CSS alone; you'd need to use javascript to detect whether the sub menu is 100% visible, and if not, position from the bottom instead of top.

Comment: Wow this sounds complicated for such issue.. I have met somewhere similar menu and think it was done by css only, or I am wrong?

Comment: You want logic. When the sub menu is not visible, you want to change the way it gets positioned. That's logic. CSS doesn't do logic. If you know of a solution that does what you want, then by all means, paste the link. Of course, you could just hard-code everything, but that wouldn't be a flexible solution.

Comment: @Christian is not that simple because if sub menu is paritial visible, for example anly few of the sub options are visible, the rest not? Can you provide js code that can detect such situation? thanks, the problem is I dont remember where I saw the similar menu..

Comment: Exactly. That's why you need logic, as I described in my last comment. Please, try and solve it yourself first. We aren't here to write code for you for free - you need to at least attempt to write a solution yourself before we can assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a class to the last `ul`, say `.dropup`, then one can add custom CSS for that `ul`:

```
ul.subul.dropup{top:auto;bottom:0;}
```

This will make the bottom of the last menu item be aligned with the bottom of the menu.

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3mp160u2/).